# d3.js Bar Chart - No Y Axis scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3.js bar chart, but the X axis columns have no height, presumably because there is no data/scale for the Y axis.  The last column should display.

[image]

The JSON:

```
[{"Domain":"Knowledge","Knowledge":0},{"Domain":"Problem Solving","problem_solving":0},{"Domain":"Skill","skill":0},{"Domain":"Transferable","transferable":100}]
```

The chart:

```
var margin = {top: 50, right: 135, bottom: 70, left: 80},
    width = 1050 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 540 - margin.top - margin.bottom;  

  var svg = d3.select("#domains")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// load the data
d3.json("json/domains.json", function(error, data) {



// Transpose the data into layers
var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["Knowledge", "Problem Solving, Skill, Transferable"].map(function(lvl) {
  return data.map(function(d) {
    return {
      x: d.Domain,
      y: d[lvl]
    };
  });
}));

  var disciplines = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d){return d.Domain})
    .rollup(function(leaves){
      return d3.sum(leaves, function(d) {return d3.sum(d3.values(d))});
    })
    .entries(data);

  // Set x, y and colors
  var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(dataset[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }))
    .rangeRoundBands([10, width-10], 0.35, 0);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {  return d3.max(d, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; });  })])
    .range([height, 0]);

  var colors = ["#83d1c4", "#f17950", "#838BD1", "#F150BE"];

  // Define and draw axes
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5)
    .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
      .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d;     
  });

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .outerTickSize(0)
  
  
  d3.select('.y axis .tick:first-child').remove();
  
  var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-0, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return d.y + '%';
  })
    
svg.call(tip);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .call(yAxis);


  svg.append("g")
    .call(xAxis)
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
    
    svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", 390 )
  .attr("y",  480 )
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Disciplines");
    
svg.append("text")
   .attr("x", -200 )
   .attr("y",  -40 )
   .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" )
   .attr('style', 'font-size:12px')
   .style("text-anchor", "middle")
   .text("Percentage of Learning Events");

  // Create groups for each series, rects for each segment
  var groups = svg.selectAll("g.group")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "group")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

//  var svg = d3.select("svg");
  var bar = groups.selectAll("g")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      return "translate(" + x(d.x) + ", 0)";
    });

  var sum=0;
  bar.append("rect")
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); })
    .attr('class', 'segment')
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
    .on('mouseout', tip.hide);


  columns = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("text").data(disciplines)
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d){
      return x(d.key) + x.rangeBand()/2
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
      return y(d.values);
    })
    .attr("dy", "-0.7em")
    .attr('style', 'font-size:11px')
    .text( function (d){
      return d3.format(".2f")(d.values) + '%';
    })
    .style({fill: 'black', "text-anchor": "middle"});



  // Draw legend
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(colors)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr('style', 'font-size:12px')
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(30," + i * 19 + ")";
  });

  legend.append("rect")
    .attr("x", width - 18)
    .attr("width", 18)
    .attr("height", 18)
    .style("fill", function(d, i) {return colors.slice().reverse()[i];});

  legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", width + 5)
    .attr("y", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .text(function(d, i) {
      switch (i) {
      case 0:
        return "Knowledge";
      case 1:
        return "Problem Solving";
      case 2:
        return "Skill";
      case 3:
        return "Transferable";
      }
    });
    
    });
```

I have another d3.js chart, which uses practically the same chart code as above and JSON format, just the data is different, columns and Y axis graduations show OK:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Changed 'Domain' key in the JSON to 'Dom' so as not to cause any conflict with the d3.js function `.domain` (makes no difference to the chart though...):

JSON:

```
[{"Dom":"Knowledge","Knowledge":0},{"Dom":"Problem Solving","problem_solving":0},{"Dom":"Skill","skill":0},{"Dom":"Transferable","transferable":100}]
```

Chart:

```
var margin = {top: 50, right: 135, bottom: 70, left: 80},
    width = 1050 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 540 - margin.top - margin.bottom;  

  var svg = d3.select("#domains")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// load the data
d3.json("json/domains.json", function(error, data) {



// Transpose the data into layers
var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["Knowledge", "Problem Solving", "Skill", "Transferable"].map(function(lvl) {
  return data.map(function(d) {
    return {
      x: d.Dom,
      y: d[lvl]
    };
  });
}));

  var domains = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d){return d.Dom})
    .rollup(function(leaves){
      return d3.sum(leaves, function(d) {return d3.sum(d3.values(d))});
    })
    .entries(data);

  // Set x, y and colors
  var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(dataset[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }))
    .rangeRoundBands([10, width-10], 0.35, 0);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {  return d3.max(d, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; });  })])
    .range([height, 0]);

  var colors = ["#50E0C8", "#f17950", "#C283D1", "#50BCF1"];

  // Define and draw axes
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5)
    .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
      .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d;     
  });

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .outerTickSize(0)
  
  
  d3.select('.y axis .tick:first-child').remove();
  
  var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-0, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return d.y + '%';
  })
    
svg.call(tip);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .call(yAxis);


  svg.append("g")
    .call(xAxis)
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
    
    svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", 390 )
  .attr("y",  480 )
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Domains");
    
svg.append("text")
   .attr("x", -200 )
   .attr("y",  -40 )
   .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" )
   .style("text-anchor", "middle")
   .text("Percentage of Learning Events");

  // Create groups for each series, rects for each segment
  var groups = svg.selectAll("g.group")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "group")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

//  var svg = d3.select("svg");
  var bar = groups.selectAll("g")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      return "translate(" + x(d.x) + ", 0)";
    });

  var sum=0;
  bar.append("rect")
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); })
    .attr('class', 'segment')
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
    .on('mouseout', tip.hide);


  columns = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("text").data(domains)
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d){
      return x(d.key) + x.rangeBand()/2
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
      return y(d.values);
    })
    .attr("dy", "-0.7em")
    .attr('style', 'font-size:11px')
    .text( function (d){
      return d3.format(".2f")(d.values) + '%';
    })
    .style({fill: 'black', "text-anchor": "middle"});


    
    });
```

Comment: In your JSON, the Domain value is in capital letter, but the key that has the value is lower case for some entries. Your problem might be in the _Transpose the data into layers_.

Comment: What is the D3 version you're using?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky 4 I think

Comment: @eventHandler  I tried changing those two entries from '.domain' to '.Domain', but the chart breaks (blank page).  I believe .domain is a d3.js function.

Comment: I have since updated the OP to change 'Domain'  key in the JSON to 'Dom' so as not to cause any conflict with the d3.js function 'domain'.

Comment: You have a few missing " in the line where you're defining dataset. Also is there a particular reason why you're doing stacks for column chart? The data nor the code doesn't reflect being used for stacked column charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed some errors and simplified your code. See it working in the fiddle:

```js
var margin = {top: 50, right: 135, bottom: 70, left: 80},
    width = 1050 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 540 - margin.top - margin.bottom;  

  var svg = d3.select("#domains")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// load the data
const data = [{"Domain":"Knowledge","knowledge":0},{"Domain":"Problem Solving","problem_solving":0},{"Domain":"Skill","skill":0},{"Domain":"Transferable","transferable":100}];

const normalized = data.map(item => {
  const name = item['Domain'];
  const attr = name.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '_');
  const value = item[attr];
  return {name, value};
});

console.log('N: ', normalized);
/*
// Transpose the data into layers
var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["Knowledge", "Problem Solving, Skill, Transferable"].map(function(lvl) {
  return data.map(function(d) {
    return {
      x: d.Domain,
      y: d[lvl]
    };
  });
}));

  var disciplines = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d){return d.Domain})
    .rollup(function(leaves){
      return d3.sum(leaves, function(d) {return d3.sum(d3.values(d))});
    })
    .entries(data);
*/

  // Set x, y and colors
  var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(normalized.map(item => item.name))
    .rangeRoundBands([10, width-10], 0.35, 0);

    const maxValue = normalized.reduce((max, item) => Math.max(max, item.value), 0);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, maxValue])
    .range([height, 0]);

  var colors = ["#83d1c4", "#f17950", "#838BD1", "#F150BE"];

  // Define and draw axes
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5)
    .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
      .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d;     
  });

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .outerTickSize(0)
  
  
  d3.select('.y axis .tick:first-child').remove();
  
/*
  var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-0, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return d.y + '%';
  })
    
svg.call(tip);
*/

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .call(yAxis);


  svg.append("g")
    .call(xAxis)
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
    
    svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", 390 )
  .attr("y",  480 )
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Disciplines");
    
svg.append("text")
   .attr("x", -200 )
   .attr("y",  -40 )
   .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" )
   .attr('style', 'font-size:12px')
   .style("text-anchor", "middle")
   .text("Percentage of Learning Events");

  // Create groups for each series, rects for each segment
  var groups = svg.selectAll("g.group")
    .data(normalized)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "group")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

  groups.append("rect")
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    .attr("x", d => x(d.name))
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y(0) - y(d.value); })
    .attr('class', 'segment')
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    // .on('mouseover', tip.show)
    // .on('mouseout', tip.hide);


  columns = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(normalized)
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d){
      return x(d.name) + x.rangeBand()/2
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
      return y(d.value);
    })
    .attr("dy", "-0.7em")
    .attr('style', 'font-size:11px')
    .text( function (d){
      return d3.format(".2f")(d.value) + '%';
    })
    .style({fill: 'black', "text-anchor": "middle"});



  // Draw legend
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(colors)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr('style', 'font-size:12px')
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(30," + i * 19 + ")";
  });

  legend.append("rect")
    .attr("x", width - 18)
    .attr("width", 18)
    .attr("height", 18)
    .style("fill", function(d, i) {return colors.slice().reverse()[i];});

  legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", width + 5)
    .attr("y", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .text(function(d, i) {
      switch (i) {
      case 0:
        return "Knowledge";
      case 1:
        return "Problem Solving";
      case 2:
        return "Skill";
      case 3:
        return "Transferable";
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>


<div id="domains" />
```

Comment: This is what i meant in my comment to the OP. Thanks for testing this.

Comment: I may have given this too quickly - I didn't notice that the load data via ajax was replaced with static data.  How do I use this code and the ajax data?

Comment: @IlludiumPu36 replace `const data = ...` with `d3.json("json/domains.json", (error, data) => { ...` and put all the code below within the function body

Comment: I did that, but not showing the graph at all.  d3.json("json/domains.json", (error, data) => {

const normalized = data.map(item => {
  const name = item['Domain'];
  const attr = name.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '_');
  const value = item[attr];
  return {name, value};
});...rest of code....then });

Comment: The static data does of course work, so I'll accept the solution, but I still need to load the JSON via ajax...but I can't get that to work.

Comment: Print to console the data you get from `d3.json`. What do you see?

Comment: OK, I changed 'Domain' to 'Dom' previously (see update in OP) and that was why the chart wasn't displaying.  Now having changed things back to 'Domain' the chart displays and I get 100% showing on the last column but no bar or vertical scale.  Errors are: d3.min.js:1 Error: <rect> attribute y: Expected length, "NaN".      Error: <rect> attribute height: Expected length, "NaN".    Error: <text> attribute y: Expected length, "NaN"

Comment: But if I switch back to the static data no problems....

Comment: the data is EXACTLY the same.  I may open a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73371489/1911619